# PHP MySQL select data where in column array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

If I have a table called 'invitation' like this:

```
| invitation_id | sender | recipient             |
| 1             | Josh   | James, Hendry, Max    |
| 2             | Steave | James, Gerrard, Ramon |
| 3             | Steave | Gerrard, Max          |
```

How can I show invitation data that I received, if my name is "James"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `like %james%` you may get incorrect results, if similar name occurs. So using `find_in_set` can solve your problem.

```
select * from invitation where find_in_set('james',recipient) <> 0
```

You can also use `like` in this way.

```
select * from invitation where ',' + recipient + ',' like '%,james,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM invitation
WHERE recipient LIKE '%james%'
```

Comment: This will do the job but you will face trouble if there is another recipient called James Bond :)

Answer (score 1):

**Storing the data (recipient) in comma separated is really not a good practice.**

But you still can use [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

You should `iterate` with you all the values of recipient and do like this

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('James','James,Hendry,Max')

SELECT FIND_IN_SET('James','James, Gerrard, Ramon')
```

Which will return `0` or `1`

Answer (score 0):

Use of `LIKE` will be good for searching purpose.
But We should use the function `FIND_IN_SET()` for this type of problem, Where data in table exist as comma separated format.